# Can't get reducer stream to work in Java. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

I want to use a reducer to sum up all the inputs from 'args', then divide by the args length to get the result I'm looking for (just a simple function to learn java).

I'm following (as far as I can tell) the instructions from every tutorial I can find on getting the stream library to work, but still no luck. TY for any help in advanced.

```
public class AverageNumbers { 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
     int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); 
     int y = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); 
     int z = Integer.parseInt(args[2]); 

     int sum = args.stream().reduce(0, (acc, cur) -> Integer.parseInt(acc) + Integer.parseInt(cur), Integer::sum); 
  
     // int math = sum / args.length; 

     System.out.println(sum); 
   } 
}
```

I've tried:

1. Importing the java.utils.stream function
2. rewriting the stream as Stream.of(args)
3. rewriting the stream to return a string to reduce potential complexity of type casting

Answer (score 2):

There is no `.stream()` method on arrays.

You can do the following instead:

1. Use `Arrays.stream` to get a stream of `String`s from `args`.
2. Use `mapToInt` with `Integer.parseInt` to get an `IntStream`.
3. Directly call the `sum` method (which exists on `IntStream`) to get the total.

```java
int sum = Arrays.stream(args).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).sum();
double average = 1d * sum / args.length;
// Multiplying by the double value 1 is necessary to prevent integer division
```

The average can also be obtained directly through [`IntStream#average`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#average--).

```java
double average = Arrays.stream(args).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).average().orElseThrow();
```

Or `Collectors.averagingInt`:

```java
double average = Arrays.stream(args).collect(Collectors.averagingInt(Integer::parseInt));
```

Comment: This worked, combined with importing the java.util.Arrays namespace/ package

Comment: If you are ultimately after the average then collecting with `Collectors.averagingInt` is a more direct approach

Comment: @sprinter Indeed, I've updated to show the use of `IntStream#average` and `Collectors.averagingInt`.

Comment: There is no need to multiply with `1d` to convert an `int` to `double`. You could use a type cast, but it’s even simpler to declare `double sum = …` in the first place.